# scp to remote server asking for passphrase despite adding public key to authorized keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

There are several similar questions on Stack Overflow itself, but none worked.

I have a server called `remote` and I am trying to copy some file from my `local` machine. Both are Ubuntu machines : `local` is Ubuntu 16 and `remote` is Ubuntu 14.

I have added my `local` public key to the `remote` server at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Before adding the keys I was prompted for the password to the remote machine, but now I am being prompted for the key passphrase.

There are my permissions on the remote machine :

```
drwx------ 2 ops ops 4096 Dec  5 07:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 ops ops 4096 Dec  6 02:06 ..
-rwx------ 1 ops ops  743 Dec  5 03:56 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 ops ops 3326 Dec  5 04:04 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 ops ops  751 Dec  5 04:04 id_rsa.pub
-rwx------ 1 ops ops  444 Dec  5 06:55 known_hosts
```

This is my verbose ssh log :

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gateway [172.16.24.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ops/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gateway:22 as 'ops'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TgaQlbi1L+JBQBbqhJZHIpDnXtJGZtw5y3r2fj7qFAM
debug1: Host 'gateway' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ops/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ops/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ops/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: I think this prompt is for the passphrase of _local_ private key. It is needed to decrypt the key and start the handshaking process for SSH connection. You might have set that when you generated the key on local machine.

Comment: yes I did set a password while creating the key for `local`. Shall I again generate without password? I don't think this is the issue because its working for a different pair of machines setup in a similar manner.

Comment: I generated my key again without a passphrase and this works now. Thanks .

Comment: It is a trade off between security and convenience. If you do that that then anyone having read access to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or physical access to your machine can see your unencrypted private key. They can use it to impersonate you without knowing any passphrase. You may have to make this choice if you want to make automated connections to other machines.

Comment: @pii_ke : Yeah security will be a big concern now. Is there any way where I can use passphrase for my key, but still not prompted for passphrase for these particular pair of machines, maybe some sort of exception. But again, this makes no sense, as this will be a safe corridor for a hacker.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your key is password protected. It is prompting you to unlock that not log into the server.